# Parse.com requests don't get any answer or exception

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am developing a small social app for posting news, rating and posting comments.
I have implemented an EndlessAdapter that loads data from Parse.com.

My problem is that when I quickly click on 'Refresh' button several times (let's say, 7-8 times, just for testing purposes), I got into a strange situation: Parse.com neither gives me response, nor gives and exception or timeout error. My progressbar is rolling and nothing happens. And the only option to get things back to work is just shutting down the app and launching it again.

Is there any limitations on a number of  simultaneous requests from one device? How can I trace what happens with my request? Is there any `debug`-mode to track all the requests to and responses from Parse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which HTTP library are you using?

Comment: I'm using Parse android SDK. Not performing any raw HTTP-requests.

Comment: use a debuggable httpclient ( WIRE & HEADERS ) and switch to the REST API and you will see everything in the logs.

Comment: @RobertRowntree that defeats the purpose of using Parse - their SDK simplifies HTTP requests for you

Comment: @RobertRowntree I've seen your answer in separate thread about scalability :) This is the option, but I have no time to implement it at the moment.

Comment: @AndrewBreen Robert figured out that rest api requests are faster than using parse android sdk. Sad but true.

Comment: That test on parse scale was 2 years ago, and AsnycTask in Android, IMO has changed since then. So, there may be ways to work with it that did not exist back then? Back then , IMO parse were clearly single threaded within their impl of AsyncTask. That is not necessarily true now if Parse have changed their SDK to match android improvements?? SDK gets u to-market sooner, but what then when you need to scale and to have really fast network layer on your 'cloud-first' app?

Comment: @agamov hey, i'm having same issue with parse response. How you solved that problem?

Comment: @Palaima I wasn't able to solve it. Parse.setLogLevel didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `Parse` class, you can set the log level as such:

`Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);`

This will then let you see exactly what is happening within the Parse requests.

Comment: I put this line in Application object and in my main Activity. I can't see any detailed info about what's happening. Hell.

Comment: can you see any parse logs in your device's LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

With Rest API in addition to an HttpClient lib you would choose, although its much more time in dev, you get easy answer in debug mode about what happens with every Http message, and you can set exception thresholds on any aspect of host connection or req/resp cycles...

see conn + request [config here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientConfiguration.java)

see Wire + Header [logs here](http://pastebin.com/7eU9GUKV) tracking every http message In/Out to Parse.com...

various httpclient libs for android will let you do this sort of thing if needed.